# Can order By date and also if status == "Completed" it should go to end of list in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to get queries order by the **end date** also if the **status** is == completed, I want to show it last if the date is order by or not. The below code gives me a result as order by the end date. it's work but if the status is equal how does it sort into the last in the list? my status column has "Processing", "Completed"

```
$this->paperorders = paperorder::with('order', 'client', 'paperorders', 'papers', 'stocks')->orderBy('end_at', 'asc')->get();
```

[DB Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNgt6.png)

Comment: $this->paperorders = paperorder::with('order', 'client', 'paperorders', 'papers', 'stocks')->orderBy('end_at', 'asc')->orderBy('status', 'desc')->get();

Comment: you can use orderByRaw like  ->orderByRaw("FIELD(status , 'completed', 'pending', 'delayed', 'closed') ASC")

Comment: ->orderByRaw("FIELD(status , 'completed', 'pending', 'delayed', 'closed') ASC") this is work for me. Thanks a lot.